# SQL JOIN from assignment table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot, left-join

I have the following tables:

`rooms`

```
rid | roomname   | ...
----------------------
1   | Pantry     | ...
2   | Conference | ...
...
```

`employees`

```
eid | lastname  | firstname
---------------------------
1   | Zufall    | Rainer
2   | Piper     | Peter
....
```

`assignments`

```
aid | room | employee | weekday
-------------------------------
1   |  2   |   1      |   1
2   |  2   |   1      |   2
3   |  2   |   2      |   3
4   |  2   |   1      |   4
5   |  2   |   1      |   5
6   |  1   |   2      |   1
7   |  1   |   2      |   3
8   |  1   |   2      |   5
```

Now I want to write a query, listing me all rooms and their assignments in the following format:

```
roomname   | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday
--------------------------------------------------------------
Conference | Zufall | Zufall  |   Piper   |  Zufall  |  Zufall
Pantry     | Piper  |  NULL   |   Piper   |   NULL   |  Piper
```

I wrote the query

```sql
SELECT r.roomname, e.lastname AS Monday
FROM rooms AS r
LEFT JOIN assignments AS a ON r.rid = a.room AND a.weekday = 1
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON a.employee = e.eid
```

what gives me all assignments for monday, but how can I combine that with the assignments on the other weekdays?

Thanks in advance.
Lars

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: can you show what result you expected?

Comment: @MohammadShehroz They did

Comment: @Strawberry I saw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    r.roomname, 
    max(case when a.weekday = 1 then e.lastname end) monday,
    max(case when a.weekday = 2 then e.lastname end) tuesday,
    max(case when a.weekday = 3 then e.lastname end) wednesday,
    max(case when a.weekday = 4 then e.lastname end) thursday,
    max(case when a.weekday = 5 then e.lastname end) friday
from rooms as r
left join assignments as a on r.rid = a.room
left join employees as e on a.employee = e.eid
group by r.roomname, r.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT r.roomname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.weekday = 1 THEN e.lastname END) AS Monday,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.weekday = 2 THEN e.lastname END) AS Tuesday,
       . . .
FROM rooms r LEFT JOIN
     assignments a
     ON r.rid = a.room LEFT JOIN
     employees e
     ON a.employee = e.eid
GROUP BY r.roomname;
```